# Hide all windows for a process (ex. Internet Explorer)

Tags: .net, interop, pinvoke, watin

I am using WatiN to script actions in Internet Explorer that run in the background of the user's machine.  (I know...hacky).  I am able through WatiN to make the Internet Explorer window not show.  However, during my script, some HTML dialogs are opened.  I am able to hide them using the P-Invoke ShowWindow in User32.dll, but they still appear for a second or so while I find the HWnd for the dialog.  My question is:

Is there a way to stop a process from showing any windows?

Thanks

Comment: how about giving context ... seriously

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you tried the AutoCloseDialogs property on the IE object's Settings property in WatiN?

One option would be to run the whole thing under a different user account. I'm not sure what is invoking WatiN but the [CreateProcessAsUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasusera) Windows API will, by default, put whatever processes it create's in a separate interactive desktop i.e. not the current user's one. [This blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/alejacma/how-to-call-createprocesswithlogonw-createprocessasuser-in-net) has some info on calling CreateProcessAsUser from .net.

Answer (score 0):

```
ie.ShowWindow(NativeMethods.WindowShowStyle.Hide);
```